# message to a superclass's property

Tags: objective-c, ios, properties

I have a text field that is an IBOutlet in a CustomCell class. Then that cell gets instantiated in a UITableViewController subclass. Last I have a subclass of the UITableViewController. How can I send messages to the text field from the last subclass? Thanks!

```
//CustomCell.h
@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell
@property (retain) IBOutlet UITextField *textField

//DetailViewController.h
#import CustomCell.h
@interface DetailViewController : UITableViewController
@property (retain) IBOutlet CustomCell *CustomCell

//DetailViewController.m  just the cell getting instantiated.

static NSString *CustomCellIdentifier = @"CustomCellIdentifier";
DetailViewCell *cell = 
 (DetailViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellIdentifier];

if (!cell) {        
      [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
      cell = customCell;
}

//AddItemViewController.h
#import DetailViewController.h
@interface AddItemViewController : DetailViewController

//AddItemViewController.m

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    textField.text = @"The text" //obviously this doesn't work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be exposing cells directly through a property rather you should access the datasource.

In your example though `AddItemViewController` inherits from `DetailViewController` which has the property `CustomCell` so you need to access the textField from that property.

```
self.CustomCell.textField.text = @"The text";
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `cell.textField.text`;.  You will probably have to do that in this method:

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`